# Is there any way to automatically link in-text citation to individual references on the reference list?

Tags: publications

I have an article with in-text citations and list of references. I have not used any of reference managers, just used word. 
Is there any way to automatically link in-text citation to individual references on the reference list?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this in word but PDF LaTex outputs can do this quite easily.

Comment: As above, I don't know of a way to do this with Word, but if you use LaTeX, this can be done by including the [hyperref](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#Hyperref) package.

Comment: This solution works in Word 2010. Other versions may have different mechanisms. Move the cursor to your literature reference. Go to the "Insert" tab, click "Bookmark" in the "Links" group - now you have a bookmark for this particular reference. Then mark your in-text citation, go again to "Insert" and click on "Cross-reference" in the "Links" group. You'll get a dialog where you can link to the bookmark you previously established. Unfortunately, you'd have to do all this manually, no automation there... I guess you would need to use a ref manager or LaTeX with hyperref.

Comment: @CTKlein and Mangara: no, there would be the exact same problem with LaTeX if I understand correctly, and it cannot be solved automatically. If I read well, the OP has written citations in text form "[Knuth, 85]", not "\cite{Knuth85}", and wants to convert them automatically to the latter (or an equivalent version with Word).

Comment: In any case, @user92953, please edit the question and be more explicit or add an example. It is difficult to understand your exact problem. What do you mean by "link" for instance?

Comment: After reading @FedericoPoloni's comment to my answer, I am wondering if I misread the question. Do you want to do this for future documents or you want a way to scan existing text and auto-generate references for them. Please clarify because I think one and it seems at least one person thinks something else.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is quite easy to do, once you know how.

First, go to the References tab, then click on Insert Citation and Add New Source.
[image: Word 1]

Next, fill out the information as appropriate.
[image]

When you want your References List produced, go to Bibliography.
[image]

This is extremely helpful when you need to change some detail (say publication date) and you have many citations to the same material. Change it in one place and Word will update all of the in-text citations as well as the references list.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP asked for (see my comment to the question).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni They are asking how to automatically add a link to a reference. In order to do this, it might be necessary to extract the document's title using a [citation parser](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22citation+parser%22).

Answer (score -1):

Highlight the link, right click, click "Link", Make sure you select the tab on the right that says "Existing File or Web Page" then click OK.